# How to run node js and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

My question is simple How to run a server node js and a react app in same time?
My package.json

```js
{
  "name": "mon-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {       
    "start": "concurrently \"node server.js\" \"react-scripts start\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

I use concurrently
Moreover npm start runs of course the dev server
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does that not work? What is your question?

Comment: How to run react and node without the dev server in the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try doing something like this:

```js
{
  "name": "mon-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node server.js",
    "client": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes great code :) thanks a lot 
But in production without the react dev node server 
How is it run? 
I have the node server but to  the side of react what is a solution to display the react web page?

Comment: when you build and deploy the app, you don't have the react dev server. In production, you'll only have the node server which will send you all the frontend files.

Comment: Thanks a lot I gonna try :)

Comment: the build shell works but i would like to display my react app using the route on my node app server it doesn't work thank for the heelp

Comment: It's resolved using "react-scripts build", in "client "and connect my node server to build/index.html with the route app.get('/' etc and replace in "client" after react-scripts start 
Thanks four your help :)